On complex impedance representation and Riemann surfaces
We know that a complex number, $z=re^{i\phi}$, can be represented with infinitely many phases, $\phi+2\pi n$, for integer $n$, as can be easily seen from the equivalent picture of a vector on the Argand diagram. Then, when we have a mutli-valued function, e.g. like square root, in the complex domain, the situation changes and we get branch cuts and Riemann surfaces (sheets) that we can work on. The math is clear. And physically speaking, moving from one Riemann surface/sheet to another (crossing the branch cut) usually implies that we have crossed a discontinuity or a source term (e.g. charge density term).
I noticed that in traditional physics and engineering textbooks, when we get a complex impedance (of a circuit for example): $Z=x+iy$, textbooks usually say that we can represent this with magnitude $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ and phase $\phi=\arctan y/x$. They don’t say $\phi=\arctan y/x + 2\pi n$. As if they have implicitly confined themselves to the principal value (with $n=0$), and therefore only one Riemann surface to work on later.
Why is that so?
Could it be that, when talking about an isolated impedance in general as a concept, there is no implication of any discontinuities to give Riemann sheets? Any ideas would be appreciated.

The impedance of an RLC network is meromorphic, specifically a rational function being the ratio of two polynomials on the complex plane, it is single-valued. The impedances of networks containing transmission lines are also single-valued and meromorphic but are not rational functions, they contain function such as tanh z, and some such. Riemann surfaces do show up in scattering problems, see Sommerfeld's solution of edge scattering off a half-plane, and, with a bit of a stretch, one could say that scattering is a kind of impedance problem for propagating waves.

@hyportnex Thanks for your nice answer. Could it also be that dealing in practice with complex numbers is different from complex functions? As a concrete example, say I have a ratio of two numbers $s=(R+i\omega L)/(G+i\omega C)$, where $R,L,G,C$ are real circuit values. Now, if we express $s$ in terms of magnitude and phase, can we write the phase of $s$ without the rotations $e^{i2\pi n}$? This will later be important if we want to define a new parameter $\gamma=\sqrt{s}$, which we can only consider multi-valued if we had kept $n$ in the phase of $s$. In textbooks, they don't usually keep $n$

@hyportnex ... (continued) and looking at $s$ in this example as a complex number, can we say it is a meromorphic function f(z)? What would be the complex variable $z=re^{i(\phi+2\pi n)}$ here, if the values $R,L,C,G$ are given real numbers?  My original question arose while solving such a problem and then I thought for a moment whether we should taken these phase rotations for writing $s$. Textbooks seem to only take the principal phase, when going from $x+iy$ to $re^{i\phi}$, with $\phi$ taken as $\arctan y/x$ instead of $\arctan y/x +2\pi n$.

If you set $z=i\omega$ then the function $s(z)=(R+zL)/(G+zC)$ is a rational function of the complex variable $z$, and hence it is meromorphic. (Meromorphic: in any finite region of its domain the function has finite number of poles and zeros; this covers both impedance and admittance.) The function $\gamma =\sqrt{z}$ is indeed multivalued, it is the wave impedance of a passive homogeneous transmission line and has two branches, $+$ or $-$, of which only one is passive and thus physical, this is the one that is the positive branch continuation of $+\sqrt{R/G}$, since $R>0$ and $G>0$.

There are some so-called active "transmission lines", a periodic sequence of active elements in a long chain usually ladder, transistors with RLC, whose behavior can be modeled as a transmission line and there one may choose to model the propagation behavior with an equivalent $\gamma$ on the "negative" branch. But these are unrelated to the multivalued nature of the polar representation of complex numbers, which is related to the singularity of the coordinate transformation $[x,y] \to [r,\phi]$ at $r=0$ and not to the physics of it.

@hyportnex Brilliant! Many thanks.

Since the physical quantity is $Z$, the extra $2\pi n$ does not matter. In fact it is a good sanity check, as any physical quantity you compute must be independent of it, if not, it is due to an error. On another note, there is no discontinuity when considering branches. On the contrary, the idea behind Riemann surfaces is to glue different sheets to get rid of discontinuities. You sacrifice single validness for continuity.
First off, you need to clearly define what is the complex function you are considering. In electric circuits, you are typically interested in the function $Z(s)$, the $s$-domain impedance which arises from the Laplace transform. To see an example of Riemann sheets, you'll need to consider infinite circuits. Indeed, for a finite network of ideal resistors, capacitors and inductors, $Z$ will only be meromorphic. When the number is infinite, the poles can coalesce to a branch cut.
I will illustrate these general considerations with a concrete example. take the wave guide like in FLP II.22-6. Normalising the capacitance $C=2$ and the inductance $L=2$, you arrive at the equation:
$$
Z = s+\frac1{2s+\frac1{Z+s}}
$$
which you solve to:
$$
Z = \sqrt{1+s^2}
$$
As you can see, there are only two branch points at $s=\pm1$, which correspond to the cutoff frequency. You can construct the associated Riemann surface by adding a branch cut along $[-i,i]$, and you get two branches depending on the sign of the square root. The natural branch to consider is to choose $Z>0$ when $s\in\mathbb R_+^*$. This can be motivated by considering a finite number of element, where $Z(s>0)>0$ and the poles are in $[-i,i]$ and will coalesce to the segment in the infinite limit.
Btw, the continuum limit is obtained by looking at the limit $s\to0$ or equivalently large cutoff frequencies. In this limit, the two branch points merge at infinity to give a regular point so you recover in this limit a single valued complex function:
$$
Z = 1
$$
As you can see, $Z$ can be multivalued, but the physical branch can always be chosen by reverting to a finite model. You can also motivate it directly from causality or energy considerations. You can consider auxiliary quantities like $\phi=\arg Z$, but since they are not physical, there is no natural branch to choose, but this ambiguity disappears when computing physical quantities.
Hope this helps.
